# Login failed for user Error: 18456 State: 10

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, permissions, security, logins

In one of my vb.net applications I am getting the error `Login failed for user 'user'.`
But the user has full permission (sysadmin). Also this error happens intermittently.

Error log has the following:

> Login failed for user 'user'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT:
>   192.168.1.69] 
> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38. 
>   
> Login
>   failed for user 'user'. Reason: Password validation failed with an
>   infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT:
>   192.168.1.61]
>   
> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 10. 
>   
> Login
>   failed for user 'user'. Reason: Password validation failed with an
>   infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT:
>   192.168.1.88]
> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 10.

I saw  [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456).

But in my case all database are set to autoclose OFF.

Also the user exist and has sysadmin permission.

Also [KB #925744](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925744) is for SQL Server 2005 as mentioned in the article. But I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

update:

I just saw this [article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2679/sql-server-login-failure-error-18456-severity-14-state-10/). In that there was query to find ring buffer.In my case i got 0x139F as error code.when i run  NET HELPMSG 5023 i got following.

```
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.
```

What does this mean? Whether it will be reason for the error?

Comment: The error log excerpt has a number of different errors at different times from different clients. Are all of these part of the problem you're investigating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state 38 error is probably a red herring: focus on the state 10 errors.

While [KB Article #925744](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925744) says it is for SQL Server 2005, that is simply because of the date it was written. The symptom it causes would affect all versions of SQL Server that have been released since then in similar or identical ways.

Now, if `user` is a Windows login, perhaps you are somehow trying to authenticate as a Windows login without specifying the domain, or perhaps you are specifying the domain but the domain controller is unreliable or on an unreliable network connection. You should post your actual connection string in the question (fudging our real names/passwords of course).

You should also consider creating a new, separate login with the same permissions, and see if you intermittently get the same error with that other user as well - my guess this is an architectural problem in some way as opposed to a problem with just this user.

Another possibility is if your .net application is using Windows auth and the underlying password has been changed. Seems like a long shot, but check out the article and there is a hotfix available: [KB Article #2545850](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545850).

Comment: The user is having sql authentication. Also the error didn't repeat every time for that line of code. The error didn't happen during sql connection,it is during accessing data using  recordset open command

Comment: I have also updated the question.Please check

Comment: The error solved after un-checking password policy check box.

Comment: @ITresearcher so was the user somehow created with a not-complex-enough password?

Comment: May be.But sql server allows to create login with password policy checked having simple password.For example if i give password as 'abc' and check the password policy no warning comes while creating user. Also i can't understand the the error 5023  and the error which actually happend in my case.Anyway now the error is solved.

Comment: @ITresearcher SQL Server should only allow creation of simple password if/while the local password policy is disabled or set to very simple rules. So maybe user was created before policy was enforced.

Comment: May be that is the case. The login was created about 3 years back.I don't know whether any changes are done after that.So i am not sure about it.